# Extending an existing Spotlight importer

Tags: cocoa, metadata, spotlight

I would like to use OS X Spotlight to search an image by rating (programmatically within an app I'm working on).

I tried to create a "smart folder" in Finder with the following query (I created it with Finder, and found this textual representation in File->Get Info):

((kMDItemKind = "JPEG image*"cdwt) && (kMDItemStarRating > 0))

However, the result is empty, although I do have rated images on my disk.

Further investigation revealed that Spotlight does not index this metadata property for images.

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/Importers.html), it's not possible to provide a custom spotlight importer to a file type which already has an importer provided by OS X.

Despite this, I wonder if there is a way to "extend" Spotlight to store and index the image rating when it imports image files?